# Save Changes to SQL Server Database from WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, database, datagrid

I am using a WPF datagrid to display my contents in a SQL Server Database.  The contents in the datagrid are binded to a view in the database.  I populate the datagrid on window loaded by the following:

```
this.myAccountantDBDataSet = MyAccountant
    .MyAccountantDBDataSet(this.FindResource("myAccountantDBDataSet");

// Load data into the table AccountData.
this.accountDataAdapter = new MyAccountant
    .MyAccountantDBDataSetTableAdapters.AccountDataTableAdapter();
this.accountDataAdapter.Fill(myAccountantDBDataSet.AccountData);

System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource accountDataViewSource =
    (System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)
    this.FindResource("accountDataViewSource");
accountDataViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
```

What I am wondering, is how to save updates, inserts, and deletions back to the database since what I am showing in the datagrid is a view.  The database table and views looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You should really think about some `using` statements and your naming conventions for variables / objects. Those are some lengthy identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates will work, because the fields in the view map 1:1 to fields in the underlying tables, so Sql Server will be able to resolve updates in the view back to the tables (even `AccountType`).

Inserts will not work because `Account.AccountTypeId` can not be set and I assume that it is a mandatory field.

Deletes will not work, because Sql Server cannot tell which record in which table you are trying to delete.

I think in this case, you can just as well work with `Accounts` records and show `AccountTypeId` in a [`DataGridComboBoxColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx) that has `AccountData` as datasource, displays `AccountData.AccountType` and binds to `Account.AccountTypeId`.

Comment: My hope was to use this field as a textcolumn though.  I want it to show the value of the Account Type for Accounts already entered.  However, when the user adds a new Account, they can type in the Account Type.  I eventually want this column to be like an AutoCompleteTextBox,when a user starts typing, it will show suggestions of Account Types already entered, if the user types something different, the new type will be added.

Comment: I think you better start working with view models as in MVVM. You can define autocomplete lists in it and let your controller handle lookup of id's by name.